# Delaying progress indicator

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code in my layout page so whenever an Ajax request is sent, it'll show a progress-please-wait panel.

but I'm not sure how to put a delay to it.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function (event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions) {
    $('#wait').modal('show');
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions) {
    $('#wait').modal('hide');
});
```

I tried:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function (event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions) {
    setTimeout("$('#wait').modal('show')", 3000);
});
```

But if a request takes less than 3000 ms, the in progress indicator shows up and never goes away becaue `ajaxComplete` is already done by then.

So I guess in the `setTimeout`, I have to check if the current ajax is already done, if it is, then do not bother to show the panel, else, show it and `ajaxComplete` will hide it later. However, I do not know how to check for its current status in `ajaxStart`.

Comment: In order to give a sensible progress bar you would need to know certain quantities e.g. x kb's to be transferred already y kb's done. Without that or any other feedback of how much is left to do, any progress bar is essentially only a "I'm still working" indicator. Also, in order to close the progress bar you should utilize the complete event not just set a random timeout. http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

Comment: @BjoernRennhak, not really a progress bar, but a "please wait..." panel. I'm also using ajaxComplete event to hide the panel, but it conflicts with the setTimeout.

Comment: Define your timeout via the ajaxSetup method that should solve the problem? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

Comment: Can you have simultaneous ajax requests?

Comment: @zerkms, yes. that can happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I guess in the setTimeout, I have to check if the current ajax is already done, if it is, then do not bother to show the panel, else, show it and ajaxComplete will hide it later. However, I do not know how to check for its current status in ajaxStart.

Make a simple boolean flag for it.

```
var isLoading = false;
$(document).ajaxStart(function (event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions) {
    isLoading = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (isLoading)
            $('#wait').modal('show');
    }, 3000);
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions) {
    isLoading = false;
    $('#wait').modal('hide'); // won't do any harm if already hidden
});
```

Alternatively, you could save the timeout id in a variable and clear it when the ajax completes before the modal is shown:

```
var timer = null;
$(document).ajaxStart(function (event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions) {
    if (timer)
        return; // when multiple requests are sent at same time
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        timer = null;
        $('#wait').modal('show');
    }, 3000);
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions) {
    if (timer)
        clearTimeout(timer);
    else
        $('#wait').modal('hide');
    timer = null;
});
```

Btw, 3s seem very long to me. An UI that doesn't react after ~200ms does feel unresponsive, so I'd suggest showing the modal much earlier.

Comment: For multiple requests there should be a counter to count how many requests have finished

Comment: @zerkms: Yeah, that would be another possibility. Depends what exact behaviour you want with multiple simultaneous requests. The current code (in both snippets) shows the modal 3s after the first request and hides it with the first response. The `return` statement just ensures that there is no forgotten timeout showing a modal that gets never hidden.

Comment: @Basic: What are you commenting on? Nobody showed concerns about using counters.